# Automatically Hide the "Added to cart" WooCommerce Message after X Seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I am trying to figure out how I can hide the added to cart message after five seconds by using JS.

I am obviously not doing this correctly, and I appreciate any help I can get.

**This is the code:**

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'hide_atc_message' );
function hide_atc_message() { ?>

    <script>
 
    var addToCartMessage = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-info'), i;
        
        for (i = 0; i < addToCartMessage.length; i += 1) {
    
        setTimeout( addToCartMessage() {
        
            $('.woocommece-info').fadeOut('fast');
        
                }, 5000);
        // addToCartMessage[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    </script>

    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Having a look at the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b88b868ab8919b7c854173098b7d6d4ab227f9ee/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js#L116), when elements get successfully added to the cart, it triggers the `added_to_cart` event on the `body`, you can add your own logic binding to that event:

```js
$( document.body ).on('added_to_cart', function(fragments, cartHash, button) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('.woocommece-info').fadeOut('fast');
  }, 5000);
});
```

You seem to be mixing up some concepts.

On this line, you assign all elements with a class of `woocommerce-info` to the `addToCartMessage` `var`.

```js
var addToCartMessage = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-info'), i;
```

Then you iterate over them

```js
for (i = 0; i < addToCartMessage.length; i += 1)
```

And, for each element, you set a timeout that, if set correctly, would have faded out **all** elements with the same class after 5 seconds

```js
$('.woocommece-info').fadeOut('fast');
```

`$('.woocommece-info')` is the JQuery version of `$('.woocommece-info').fadeOut('fast');` They do a very similar thing, the difference is that with the pure JS version you get an array of elements while the JQuery query returns a JQuery collection.

You can do what you want with something like the following snippet:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
const button = document.getElementById('hide');
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      fadeOut(elements[i]);
    }
  }, 1000);
});

function fadeOut(fadeTarget) {
  const fadeEffect = setInterval(function() {
    if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
      fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
      fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    } else {
      fadeTarget.style.display = 'none';
      clearInterval(fadeEffect);
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <li class="item">one</li>
  <li class="item">two</li>
  <li class="item">three</li>
  <li class="item">four</li>
</div>
<button id="hide">Hide elements</button>
```

Or, using JQuery:

```js
$('#hide').click(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('.item').fadeOut();
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <li class="item">one</li>
  <li class="item">two</li>
  <li class="item">three</li>
  <li class="item">four</li>
</div>
<button id="hide">Hide elements</button>
```

Comment: How does that answer my question?
I am not looking for a way to click a button and hide something, I want to hide it automatically after 5 seconds. The DIV-class is called woocommerce-info

Comment: The button click is supposed to simulate reception of the `added_to_cart` event, which we don't have a way to trigger inside the snippet, you can use the code inside the click handler anywhere you want, I added an example binding to the `added_to_cart` event, which is what I am assuming you are looking for?